# What's the name of this staggered portfolio style?

Tags: website-design, style-identification

I've been trying to figure out the name of this portfolio style. Is it as simple as **Staggered**?

[image: Example 1]

[image]

I'm attempting to do something similar, but I have no idea what the style is called. I've searched for staggered, but no satisfactory results.

Comment: Among  the  general  public  it's  probably  best  known  as  the  style  used  in Pinterest,  so  if  someone  doesn't  know  what  you  mean  by " masonry  style", "Pinterest  style"  might  get across  the  type  of columns  of  thumbnails

Comment: Yes, that's right! I forgot Pinterest uses this style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called **Masonry** after bricklaying terminology.

jQuery has [plug ins](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to accomplish such layouts.